# Block shutdown process from Ruby application

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-10.04

In my Ruby application, I am recording audio and after stopping it takes about 1 minute to secure. During this period, if user shuts down the system, the audio gets corrupted.

I want to restrict the user to shutdown the system. How can I do that using Ruby?

I am using Ruby 1.9.3 and Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Show a big red alert saying "don't shutdown the system or else!"

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for your suggestion but this is not a better way for this.

Comment: Better than what? It's better than nothing. :)

Answer (score 1):

Write this in the file to make it run even when the terminal is closed:

```
Process.demon(true, true)
```

Not sure how to prevent OS shutdown. Not sure if that was your question either.